# Under Saarthal Pillar Bug?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am doing the Under Saarthal quest am and at the point where I need to rotate the 6 pillars however they will not rotate.  I read something this is a possible bug but is there any way to get around this?

Is there any way to get past just this point, even using the console if needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like loading the game from a previous save fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not only did the pillars not turn, the fire rune I'd avoided earlier on didn't even activate when I stood on it to test.
Reloading didn't work for me.
Leaving the area so it reloads didn't work.
I left the entire area and went outside where Lydia was waiting.
I grabbed her and brought her all the way back.
When I returned this time the fire rune was gone so that was good, I thought.
And the pillars now work.
Obviously this was Lydia's passive aggressive action somehow with her "I'll just be here then"
She should have just asked to come along.